# How to create two accounts in Firebase with same email

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I two apps: one for sellers and one for customers. The database is Firestore and I want to use Firebase Auth to handle authentication. If a seller wants to also become a customer under the same email address how can I set this up in Firebase Auth? For example, examplename@gmail.com has registered in the seller app and has called the createUserWithEmailAndPassword method to create his account. But when he wants to buy goods as a customer in the customer's app, he wants to register under the same email and password. But because this email already exists in firebase, how can I create the account for this different app? I don't want all customers being able to log into the sellers app without having registered to become a seller first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to separate registering the user with your app from registering them with Firebase. So the user has a single account in your project, no matter if they use a single app, or if they use both apps. Then when they open the second app, you check if they're already registered with [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#fetchsigninmethodsforemail) and if they are you call the sign-**in** method instead of sign-**up**. This approach ensures each user has a single account with a single password.

If you really want each app to have a separate account, you can allow more than [One account per email address](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/providers) in the Firebase console.